# Text colors are deprecated in API level 28

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, android-text-color

I have the code:

```
val color = if(...)
              android.R.color.darker_gray
            else
              android.R.color.secondary_text_dark
```

The value `android.R.color.secondary_text_dark` is now [deprecated in API level 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color), it says "Use a text color from your theme instead.". There is a listed constant value and a bracket " 17170437 (0x01060005)", but I cannot understand these these color values as they cannot be put in `colors.xml` because color hex values should be in the format such as `"#ffxxxx"`.

Can someone tell me what  are the  meaning of those constant numbers? Is there a different treatment to text color from usual colors? If I want to maintain the same behaviour, how should I extract those color values?

Comment: Just define your colors in the colors.xml and use [ContextCompat.getColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getcolor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging further, I realized that `android.R.color.secondary_text_dark` is actually not a color value, but rather a selector itself in the file name of `secondary_text_dark.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark_disabled"/>
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark_inverse_disabled"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark_inverse_disabled"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark_inverse"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark_inverse"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark_inverse"/>
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark_disabled"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/dim_foreground_dark"/> 
</selector>
```

With that, I can copy its content into my `res/animator` folder, extract all the color values it refers to, and call `R.animator.secondary_text_dark` from my code.